# Adding a Class on click to the element and all its previous siblings

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a ratings system for a test example. in this case, there would be 5 span elements for each star rating. In Vanilla Javascript I know i can add a class to a span to change its appearance, but what about the spans before it? For example, if i click the third star, how can i add a class of 'active" to the 3rd span and also the 1st and 2nd?

This has to be vanilla JS.

```html
<div id="ratingStars">
  <span class="star">*</span>
  <span class="star">*</span>
  <span class="star">*</span>
  <span class="star">*</span>
  <span class="star">*</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? You cannot just ask us to do everything for you. Check out rules of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe do it like this. Although, utilizing CSS may be better.

```js
document.getElementById('ratingStars').onclick = (event) => {
  let node = event.target
  if (!node.classList.contains('star')) return
  let startNode = node
  while (node) {
    node.classList.add('foo')
    node = node.previousElementSibling
  }
  node = startNode.nextElementSibling
  while (node) {
    node.classList.remove('foo')
    node = node.nextElementSibling
  }
}
```

```css
.star.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="ratingStars">
  <span class="star">*</span>
  <span class="star">*</span>
  <span class="star">*</span>
  <span class="star">*</span>
  <span class="star">*</span>
</div>
```